# solr indexing time increasing significantly with increase in documents

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

Previously my solr instance was having around 80k documents, and the average indexing time per 1k documents in batch was around 5 secs. Currently after the addition of around .25 million docs, the average indexing time per 1k documents in a batch has raised by around 6 times to around 30 secs.

The solr server uses pretty much the default configuration it came with. And relevant stack in question comprises of mysql, django, django-haystack, solr.

- Is it normal for the indexing time to increase this significantly?
- What might be the root cause for the increase in indexing time?
- Any good free tools to monitor the solr server in realtime? (Probably to narrow down to the bottleneck)
- Important solr configuration tuning, changes, optimization to look for?
- Am I missing something?